# Knockout tab binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have part on my HTML with 2 tabs.
The deafult one is working, but when I'm trying to swith the other tab, I'm getting an error.
Anybody can help why?

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="tabs: true" id="myTabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#first">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second">Second</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="first">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="second">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tabs = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).find('a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(e.target).tab('show');
        });
    }
};
```

I'm getting error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tab'

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem using  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Seems like you are missing some JS and CSS for this to be reproduced.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using jquery-ui tabs? If so, try this:
HTML

```
<div data-bind="tabs: true" id="myTabs">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#first">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#second">Second</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="first">
            <div>
                aa
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <div>
                bb
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tabs = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).tabs();
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
          $(element).tabs("destroy");
        });
    }
};
```